# Xamarin.Auth - "One or more errors occured" with Foursquare venues API

Tags: c#, xamarin, foursquare, xamarin.auth, xamarin.social

So I'm basically trying stuff with Foursquare's [venue API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) but getting the strange error whenever I send a API request.

First of all I authenticate with the following code;

```
var foursquareClient = new FoursquareClient(this);
        if(!foursquareClient.IsAuthenticated)
            foursquareClient.Authenticate();`
```

Authentication code;

```
public void Authenticate()
    {
        Log.Verbose(Logging.AppTag, "FourSquareClient:Authenticate()");

        if (this.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Log.Debug(Logging.AppTag, "FourSquareClient is already authenticated! ");
            return;
        }

        this._authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId: ClientId,
            scope: "",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.int6.org"))
        {
            AllowCancel = false
        };

        this._authenticator.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated) // auth. completed.
            {
                this.StoreAccount(eventArgs);

                var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.OwnerContext);
                builder.SetMessage("auth all good!");
                builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (o, e) => { });
                builder.Create().Show();
                return;
            }
            else // The user cancelled.
            {
                var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.OwnerContext);
                builder.SetMessage("User canncelled!");
                builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (o, e) => { });
                builder.Create().Show();
                return;
            }
        };

        // show the authenticator UI and start auth.
        var intent = this._authenticator.GetUI(this.OwnerContext);
        this.OwnerContext.StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

So if user is authenticated once, it'll store the account on device.

```
public FoursquareClient(Context context)
{
    Log.Verbose(Logging.AppTag, "Init foursquare client..");

    this.OwnerContext = context; // make sure we set the owner context before any.
    this.RetrieveAccount(); // try to retrieve any existing accounts.
}
```

Whenever he opens the application again, the account will be loaded back;

```
private void RetrieveAccount()
{
    if (this.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Log.Debug(Logging.AppTag, "FourSquareClient is already authenticated! ");
        return;
    }

    var accounts = AccountStore.Create(this.OwnerContext).FindAccountsForService("Foursquare");
    var enumerable = accounts as IList<Account> ?? accounts.ToList();

    if (enumerable.Any())
    {
        Log.Info(Logging.AppTag, "Foursquareclient found account data.");
        this.IsAuthenticated = true;
        this.Account = enumerable.First();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Info(Logging.AppTag, "Foursquareclient no account data found!");
        this.IsAuthenticated = false;
        this.Account = null;
    }
}
```

So i guess I'm all good with auth stuff but somehow can't make the request;

```
public string MakeRequest()
{
    var @params = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"v", "20120321"},
            {"ll", "44.3,37.2"}
        };
    var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore"), @params,
                                    this.Account);

    request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
                Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.Flatten()); 
            else
            {
                string json = t.Result.GetResponseText();
                Console.WriteLine(json);
            }
        });

    return string.Empty;
}
```

The request code returns; **One or more errors occured**

> 10-02 14:54:31.403 I/mono-stdout( 8641): System.AggregateException:
>   **One or more errors occured ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**
>   System.AggregateException: **One or more errors occured --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request.** 10-02 14:54:31.413 I/mono-stdout( 8641):   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult
>   result) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult
>   result) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData
>   (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in :0 
>   10-02 14:54:31.413 I/mono-stdout( 8641):   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData
>   (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in :0 
>   10-02 14:54:31.413 I/mono-stdout( 8641):   --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  -->
>   (Inner exception 0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (400) Bad Request. 10-02 14:54:31.423
>   I/mono-stdout( 8641):  --> (Inner exception 0)
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request. 10-02 14:54:31.423 I/mono-stdout( 8641):   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult
>   result) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult
>   result) [0x00000] in :0  10-02 14:54:31.423
>   I/mono-stdout( 8641):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData
>   (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData
>   (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in :0

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem by using RestSharp instead;

```
        // https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore
    public string GetVenues()
    {
        var @params = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"v", "20120321"},
                {"ll", "44.3,37.2"}
            };

        var response = this.Request("venues/explore", @params);

        return response;
    }

    private string Request(string endpoint, Dictionary<string, string> @params = null, HttpMethod httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, bool userless = false)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/");            
        var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.GET);

        if (!userless)
        {
            // About userless requests - https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth.html - Some of our endpoints that don’t pertain to 
            // specific user information, such as venues search are enabled for userless access (meaning you don’t need to have a user auth your 
            // app for access). To make a userless request, specify your consumer key's Client ID and Secret instead of an auth token in the request URL.

            request.AddParameter("oauth_token", this.Account.Properties["access_token"]);
        }

        if (@params != null)
        {
            foreach (var param in @params)
            {
                request.AddParameter(param.Key, param.Value);
            }
        }

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

        return content;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used your very first code, but added the "oauth_token" parameter manually and it works just fine :)

My code looks something like this:

```
var @params = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"oauth_token", this.Account.Properties["access_token"]},
            {"v", "20120321"},
            {"ll", "44.3,37.2"}
        };
```